# Binding textblock text from resources wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<Grid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="trackTemplateY">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="txbValueY" Text="{Binding ValueX}" Margin="5" FontSize="11" FontWeight="Medium"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=txbValueY,Mode=OneWay,Path=Text}" 
                   Background="Orange" Foreground="White"/>
```

I try this above code but i cant to bind the text, how can i bind inside resources textblock text to outside the resources, Thanks

Comment: Why you are using data template here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you are trying to show Text present in TextBlock resource in your second non-resource TextBlock.

1. You don't need DataTemplate. As you will progress ahead in WPF journey, you will come to know about those.

Below code will show "Resource Text" in your second TextBlock.

```
    <Grid.Resources>
      <TextBlock x:Key="TbRes1" Text="Resource Text" x:Name="txbValueY" Margin="5" FontSize="11" FontWeight="Medium"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource TbRes1},Mode=OneWay,Path=Text}" 
                   Background="Orange" Foreground="White"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

All sorts of problems here:

1. You're specifying Mode.TwoWay in your TextBlock Text binding, it should be Mode.OneWay.
2. You're binding to the Label's `Text` property. Label doesn't have a Text property, only Content. And it's not a dependency property so you can't bind  to it. (That said, a fluke of the internal mechanics does cause it to appear to work under certain conditions).
3. A template is exactly that: a template. You can't bind to something that doesn't exist, so the binding is meaningless.

Maybe you could clarify exactly what it is you're trying to do so we can suggest an alternative way of achieving it? Specifically, show us exactly how you're instantiating that DataTemplate.

UPDATE:

You need the first textbox to be created in order for the second one to bind to it, simply declaring it inside a DataTemplate doesn't cause that to happen by itself, so the direct binding will fail. Binding UI elements together like this should generally be avoided though, why can't you simply give the second textbox the same binding as the first?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="trackTemplateY">
            <TextBlock x:Name="txbValueY" Text="{Binding ValueX}" Margin="5" FontSize="11" FontWeight="Medium"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ValueX}" Background="Orange" Foreground="White"/>
</Grid>
```

If for some reason this isn't possible then you can also create a binding proxy object (see [this page](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/) for details):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>

        <local:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding ValueX}" />

        <DataTemplate x:Key="trackTemplateY">
            <TextBlock x:Name="txbValueY" Text="{Binding ValueX}" Margin="5" FontSize="11" FontWeight="Medium"/>
        </DataTemplate>

    </Grid.Resources>

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=proxy}, Path=Data}" Background="Orange" Foreground="White"/>
</Grid>
```

Again, there are ways to bind to the data template declaration if you really want to, but to do that I'd have to see details of how your data template is being created at runtime.

Comment: now i edit my question, please see that, then there is no way to bind inside the resources value to outside???